# stack when used in lambda is printing FIFO

Tags: lambda, java-8

I am trying to convert a decimal to binary value for which I have used Stack as my data structure. When using the normal stack pop it's printing me in correct order example for 4 the binary conversion will be 100. But I am new to java 8 and trying to use the lambda as much as I can to learn and in the process of doing it, I realized its printing FIFO ex for 4 it is printing 001.
please find the below code and let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
package com.interview.random;

import java.util.Stack;

public class ConvertDecimalToBinary {

public Stack<Integer> convertToBinary(int num){
    Stack<Integer> st=new Stack<>();
    while(num>1){
        st.push(num%2);
        num=num/2;
    }
    st.push(num);
    return st;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Stack<Integer> st=new ConvertDecimalToBinary().convertToBinary(4);

    //printing correctly
    while(!st.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(st.pop());
    }

    //Printing in FIFO not correct 
    st.forEach(i->System.out.println(i));
}
```

}

Comment: Stack works on LIFO and I am trying to use Stack for the above code when I am using stack.pop() the result I am getting with the above code is 100 and with the lambda expression I am getting 001. why is so?

Answer (score 5):

The iteration order for a `Stack` is FIFO.  This is not clearly specified in the [`Stack` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html), but that is what the implementation does.

However, the [`Stack` javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) *do* say this:

> *"A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the `Deque` interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class."*

The [`Deque` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) provides two iterators, one for FIFO order and the other for LIFO order.  The `Deque::forEach` method is specified as visiting in FIFO order, but you could do this:

dq.reverseIterator().forEachRemaining(i->System.out.println(i));

Comment: Stack works on LIFO and I am trying to use Stack for the above code when I am using stack.pop() the result I am getting with the above code is 100 and with the lambda expression I am getting 001. why is so?

Comment: you mean to say stack is not always LIFO?

Comment: I have explained.  The **iteration** order of a `Stack` is FIFO.  But (obviously) when you use `push` and `pop`, the order is LIFO.

Comment: So the expectation (expected result) forEach is FIFO for a stack?

Comment: Don’t forget, `java.util.Stack` is just an extended `java.util.Vector`, providing some methods for adding and removing at the the end of the list. Calling `push(…)` multiple times does nothing different to calling `add(…)` multiple times and `Vector.forEach(…)` still iterates the elements in the order they have been added. When you look at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Stack.html), you can clearly see which methods were added or overridden by `Stack` and which have been inherited from `Vector`. All inherited methods still bear list semantic.